# Flutter how check if an application is installed from Google Play?

Tags: flutter

Some of my applications are downloaded from the playmarket, ads are removed and posted on various sites in apk format for manual installation. Is there any legal way in flutter to check when the application is launched how it was installed?

Comment: There is a library for it, https://pub.dev/packages/store_checker

Comment: @esentis Thank you very much! I will try this package. Can you write an answer? I searched, but could not find, maybe someone else will come in handy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/store_checker) developed that checks exactly what you want.